# jQuery - hide div on load, show after animation is comlete

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-animate, hide, slideshow

I've only started coding a month or two ago and I've run into a problem that I can't seem to find a solution to.

I have a slideshow that opens up when a button is clicked, the problem that I have is that one the of the controls for the slideshow itself ('right-control') is visible when page loads.

I need it to fade in along with 'slide' when the slideshow opens up, then hide when you close the slideshow.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code for the slideshow:

//Slideshow

```
$("#slideshow").css("overflow", "hidden");

manageControls(currentPosition);

$('.control').click(function () {

    currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id') == 'right-control') ? currentPosition + 1 : currentPosition - 1;

    manageControls(currentPosition);

    $('#slides').animate({
        'left': slideWidth * (-currentPosition)
    }, 600);
});

function manageControls(position) {

    if (position === 0) {
        $('#left-control').hide();
    } else {
        $('#left-control').show();
    }

    if (position == slidesNumber - 1) {
        $('#right-control').hide();
    } else {
        $('#right-control').show();
    }
}
//End Slideshow
```

Here's my jsFiddle with full code:

http://jsfiddle.net/tVsjY/2/

Comment: What exactly is not working in your example?

Comment: Right control is visible on load, I need it to be hidden and to fade in only when the slideshow opens up. (You can see that in jsFiddle link I posted.)

Comment: So everything works, it's just I can't figure out how to hide that right control until the button is clicked and the slideshow div slides out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround for what I need to do.

Since manageControls function hides/show left/right controls depending on current position of #slides, all that needs to be done to hide **.control** on load is to also hide **#slides**.

**So if I put the following on line 9:**

```
$("#center, #slideshow, .slide").hide();
```

Then **.show** it on click - it works!

**LATEST UPDATE:**

Added the following lines to make it aesthetically applealing to the eye (control now fades into view):

```
    $(".control").stop(true).delay(1800).animate({opacity: "0.5"}, 2000);

    $(".control").stop(true).animate({opacity: "0"}, 400);
```

Here's my updated jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tVsjY/18/

P.s. It's not pretty yet, those two controls need to be fading in and out when the slideshow's activated. Will work on that next then post an update.

Answer (score 0):

I feel kinda ashamed for giving a fix instead of a solution to someone who just started coding, but maybe that's all you want.. Putting the following on line 50 of your jsfiddle should fix your problem by hiding the extra visible span:

```
$('.control').hide();
```

But the reason I am not too happy with this is because I have failed to learn and explain to you why that span shows up in the first place. I'll probably keep looking at it, but let me know if this is all you were looking for.

---

**UPDATED SOLUTION**: found the problem/solution
The controls that you hide/show in the manageControls function will always hide one and show one.

**Problem:** both controls are visible at first.
You initially call manageControls(currentPosition); on line 38, where currentPosition has a value of 0, so the left control is hidden and then the right is shown, which is already visible to begin with.

**Solution:** Replace manageControls(currentPosition); on line 38 with the following:

```
$('.control').hide(); //Hides both controls
```

Let me know if everything works/makes sense :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Adding $('.control').hide(); on either line 38 or 50 hides the control permanently, which doesn't solve my problem. I need the control (either left or right, depending on currentPosition) to be shown when slideshow's out, then hidden when it's not.

Comment: It doesn't stay permanently for me. The following seems to work perfectly on my computer (added it on line 50): http://jsfiddle.net/tVsjY/14/ & http://jsfiddle.net/tVsjY/14/embedded/result/

Comment: Really? So you can use the slideshow when you add $('control').hide();?

Comment: I found another way to do what I want to do by the way. I'll post it in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical error in your

```
function manageControls(position){}
```

You are using that function for two purposes.

1. Show/Hide the left/right controls depending on which slide you are
2. Show/Hide the left/right controls depending on whether the slider is visible or hidden.

But it always works as if it was the first scenario. My suggestion would be simply add another param to your function.

```
function manageControls(position, flag){}
```

Send a value in flag of "show", "hide" and "check" for showing both controls, hiding both controls and displaying related to slide number. And then re-write your function call according to situation.

Set the display property for .control in css to 'none'. And make the following changes in js.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var out = 0;
var currentPosition = 0;
var slideWidth = 400;
var slides = $(".slide");
var slidesNumber = slides.length;

$("#button").click(function () {

    if (out === 0) {
        manageControls(currentPosition, 'show'); // Show controls on slide show
        $("#center, #slideshow, .slide").animate({
            width: "400px"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 1900
        });
        $(".slide").delay(2000).animate({
            opacity: "1"
        }, 1500);
        out = 1;
    } else {
        manageControls(currentPosition, 'hide'); // Hide controls on slide hide
        $("#center, #slideshow, .slide").animate({
            width: "0px"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 2000
        });
        $(".slide").stop(true).animate({
            opacity: "0"
        }, 250);
        out = 0;
    }
});

//Slideshow
$("#slideshow").css("overflow", "hidden");

// No need for this line if .control set to hidden in css.
//manageControls(currentPosition);

$('.control').click(function () {

    currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id') == 'right-control') ? currentPosition + 1 : currentPosition - 1;

    manageControls(currentPosition, 'check');  // Show/hide controls on control click

    $('#slides').animate({
        'left': slideWidth * (-currentPosition)
    }, 600);
});

function manageControls(position, flag) {
    // Checks for control display
    if (flag == 'check') {
        if (position === 0) {
            $('#left-control').hide();
        } else {
            $('#left-control').show();
        }

        if (position == slidesNumber - 1) {
            $('#right-control').hide();
        } else {
            $('#right-control').show();
        }
    } else if (flag == 'show') {
        $('.control').show();
    } else if (flag == 'hide') {
        $('.control').hide();
    }
}
//End Slideshow
});
```

But you need to review your code. It might be that you are a beginner but you should always work on optimizing your code. And you code needs that.

Comment: It wasn't a logical error, manageControls was only being used to show/hide left/right control depending on which slide I was on, it wasn't being used to show controls depending on whether or not the slideshow was visible or not. Which was the problem I was having from the very beginning, I can't figure out the code to show left/right control when the slideshow is visible or hidden.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it's a start for me. Unfortunately though, it doesn't work. It shows both controls on load, when the slideshow is invisible. Any other suggestions? P.s. Do you have any suggestions as to how/where I need to optimize my code?

Comment: I tested and it works. Did you add the style definition that I said "Set the display property for .control in css to 'none'."?

Comment: I did. What I meant is that it's not that it doesn't work at all, it's that it doesn't work in the way I need it to. It displays both controls on click, whereas it's supposed to hide left/right control depending on currentPosition. I'm still playing around with it, will try to get it to work properly. As I said, I found a workaround.